# Observable switch/flatMap fires instantly

Tags: facebook, angular, rxjs

I have the following code in my service:

```js
public loginWithFacebook(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Login');
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.fb.login()).flatMap((userData) => {
      return this.http.post(authFacebook, {access_token: userData.authResponse.accessToken}, { observe: 'response' });
    }).do( (response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      const token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
      if (token) {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
      }
    });
  }

  getFacebookProfile():Observable<any> {
    console.log("Get Profile");
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.fb.getLoginStatus())
        .filter((state) => state.status === 'connected')
        .switchMapTo(Observable.fromPromise(this.fb.api('/me')));
  }
```

And later I use it in my component to get the profile info once login is successful.

```
this.profileData = this.usersService.loginWithFacebook()
    .flatMapTo(this.usersService.getFacebookProfile());
```

However, for some reason getFacebookProfile() fires instantly even before the login procedure is complete. And I get an authentication error. Also, I have to login twice to get profile info displayed.

I've been always thinking that switchMap and flatMap only switch to the next observable once the previous one emits a value.
What am I doing wrong here?

--EDIT--

If I subscribe to the first Observable and call getFacebookProfile() in the subscription, everything works normally. But it's not very elegant solution I feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that promises are eager. You are calling `this.fb.login()` when you compose your observable and you are passing the returned promise into `fromPromise`.

That means that the login is initiated when `loginWithFacebook` is called and not when `subscribe` is called on the observable it returns.

If you want the `login` to be deferred until `subscribe` is called, you can use [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer):

```ts
public loginWithFacebook(): Observable<any> {
  console.log('Login');
  return Observable.defer(() => Observable.fromPromise(this.fb.login()))
    .flatMap((userData) => {
      return this.http.post(authFacebook, {
        access_token: userData.authResponse.accessToken
       }, { observe: 'response' });
    })
    .do( (response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      const token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
      if (token) {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
      }
    });
}
```

For more information on using observables and promises, see Ben Lesh's article: [RxJS Observable interop with Promises and Async-Await](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875)

Comment: It sounds like it should work. But when I tried it just now I got the same result. Still fires instantly for some reason..

Comment: You will need to use `defer` in **all** of the locations where you are passing promises when composing observable chains.

Answer (score 0):

It worked at last thanks to @cartant's answer. However, for some reason, I had to wrap it with defer operator twice. I would be thankful if someone could explain why it was necessary to do it. It's a bit weird.

```js
public loginWithFacebook(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.defer(() => 
        Observable.defer(() => this.fb.login()).flatMap((userData) => 
        {
            return this.http.post(authFacebook, {access_token: userData.authResponse.accessToken}, { observe: 'response' });
        }).do( (response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            const token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
            if (token) {
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
            }
        })
    );
  }

  getFacebookProfile():Observable<any> {
    return Observable.defer(() => 
        Observable.defer(() => this.fb.getLoginStatus())
        .filter((state) => state.status === 'connected')
        .switchMapTo(Observable.fromPromise(this.fb.api('/me')))
    );
  }
```